# Magento 1.9.1.0 Sorting Fix generates an error

Tags: php, sorting, magento-1.9.1, configurable-product

Got Meogi's answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/magento-1-9-1-configurable-product-attribute-sorting) working fine at my development site. Imported a fix to my production site and got an error:

> a:5:{i:0;s:139:"Invalid method
>   FirstScribe_CatalogOptionSortFix_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::_prepareOldPrice(Array
>   (
>       (0) => 
>       (1) => 0 )

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. 
Earlier mod, which wasn't even active, hassled the outcome of the configurable.php
Deleted all the files (not only xml from the etc/modules) and all is working again.